# measure c litre using a litre and b litre (algorithm)

Tags: c++, algorithm, math

Suppose there are two jugs of a litre and b litre and i have to measure c litre by using the and b i cannot measure c if `c % gcd(a,b)!=0`.For example if a=21 and b=27 ,I cant't measure 10 litre . Can someone explain the intuition behind this?
Thanks in advance 
`AUTOCORRECT`

This was the question
https://www.codechef.com/problems/POUR1

This was the accepted code

See the statement in main `if (c % __gcd(a, b) || c > max(a, b))`
He is printing -1 as this is not possible

```
    #include<bits/stdc++.h>
    using namespace std;

    //int aa,bb,cc;

    int process(int a, int b, int c)
    {
        int sum = 1, aa = a, bb = 0;
        while (a != c and b != c) {
            int f = min(aa, b - bb);
            bb += f;
            aa -= f;
            sum++;
            if (aa == c || bb == c)
                break;
            if (aa == 0)
                aa = a, sum++;
            if (bb == b)
                bb = 0, sum++;
        }
        return sum;
    }

    main()
    {
        int t, a, b, c;
        cin >> t;
        while (t--) {
            cin >> a >> b >> c;
            //cerr << (c % __gcd(a,b)) <<'\n';
            //int aa = a , bb = b;
            if (c % __gcd(a, b) || c > max(a, b))
                cout << -1 << '\n';
            else if (c == a || c == b)
                cout << 1 << '\n';
            else
                cout << min(process(a, b, c), process(b, a, c)) << '\n';
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is pretty unclear to me, can you post the whole content of your exercise?

Comment: It's middle school arithmetic (and your formula is wrong, wher did you get the ==0 part?)

Comment: According to the code, you cannot measure c if `c % gcd(a,b) != 0`. notice the negation. That is because if statements test whether the condition is *NOT* 0

Comment: @n.m. please i want to know the math  behind this

Comment: @AdminXVII thats not negation `__` include in name of function

Comment: [math.se] maybe?

Comment: @humblefool `if (c % __gcd(a, b))` tests if `c % __gcd(a, b)` is not 0

Comment: names begin with `__` are reserved. So are names begin with `_` followed by a capital letter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bezout's Identity:

Let a and b be integers with greatest common divisor d. Then, there exist integers x and y such that ax + by = d. More generally, the integers of the form ax + by are exactly the multiples of d. (Wikipedia)

a and b here correspond to the jugs, x and y to the number of times they are used.

This proves not only that c must be a multiple of the gcd, but also that if c fulfils this condition, then a solution exists.

Answer (score 0):

A and B are both multiplied by their GCD

Thus you can be sure that after any number of transfer, both the jars will contain a number divisible by the GCD. If C is not divisible by the GCD, that means it cannot be obtained by any combination of transfers.